# ggplot - change line width

Tags: r, ggplot2

I can plot each series in a different colour in ggplot2 by doing something like this ...

```
colours <- c('red', 'blue')
p <- ggplot(data=m, mapping=aes_string(x='Date', y='value'))
p <- p + geom_line(mapping=aes_string(group='variable', colour='variable'), size=0.8)
p <- p + scale_colour_manual(values=colours)
```

Is there something comparable I can do to set different line widths for each series? (Ie. I want to use a thick red line to plot the trend and a thin blue line to plot the seasonally adjusted series.)

Comment: Can you `dput` your data (`m`)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would just add a new numeric variable to your data frame

```
##You will need to change this to something more appropriate
##Something like: 
##m$size = as.numeric(m$variable == "seasonal")
m$size = rep(c(0, 1), each=10)
```

then add a size aesthetic to your plot command:

```
p = p + geom_line(aes(group=variable, colour=variable, size=size))
##Set the size scale
p + scale_size(range=c(0.1, 2), guide=FALSE)
```

Notice that I've added `guide=FALSE` to avoid the size legend being displayed.

Comment: How do I do the contrary? I would like to make lines in the legend to be thicker, but leave lines on the plot thin.

Comment: You're probably best asking a new question

Comment: `super.useful.feature <- "guide = FALSE"`

Answer (score 8):

You could do it like:

```
x <- 1:10
y1 <- x
y2 <- 1.5*x
df <- data.frame(x=rep(x, 2), y=c(y1, y2), id=as.factor(rep(1:2, each=10)))
ggplot(df) + geom_line(aes(x=x,y=y,group=id, colour=id, size=id)) +  
scale_size_manual(values=c(1,4))
```

Comment: Agree with @Jelena-bioinf, it saves having to create a new variable in the data frame.